# File.delete() return false

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I looked for solutions in the community but unfortunately I didn't find anything that could solve.

My application already has the necessary permissions (I believe):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I'm able to create and save files perfectly, but when trying to delete with the method the return is false.

Code:

```
public static String returnDirectory() {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/FVN/";
}

String vDirectory = returnDirectory() + "Sales/";

File directory = new File(vDirectory); // Create the directory if it doesn't already exist.
if (!directory.exists()) {
    if (!directory.mkdirs()) {
        ShowMessage("Unable to create .HTML sales store directory!");
        return;
    } else {
        ShowMessage(".HTML sales store directory created!");
    }
}

File file = new File(vDirectory, "saleNumber1.html");
if (file.exists()) { // TRUE
    if (file.isFile()) { // TRUE
        if (!file.delete()) {
            showMessage("FALSE");
        } else {
            showMessage("TRUE");
        }
    }
}
```

Even proving the existence of the file and confirming that it is a real file and not a directory, in addition to having the necessary permissions, the return is false and the file is not deleted.

NOTE!!! The problem started when I had to update my app on the Play Store and I was forced to change the targetSdkVersion from 29 to 30. On Android 10 or earlier it works, the file is deleted, but on 11 and 12 it doesn't!

Comment: You need to read [this article](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage). If you move to targetSdkVersion 30, you probably need to rethink your entire file-handling process and which permissions you need.

Comment: Without knowing what `parent` is and how you obtained it, it will be difficult for people to give you more specific advice.

Comment: @JoachimSauer what I understood by reading the article is that problems should exist on Android 10 or earlier as the target of my application is now is 11 (sdk 30). Sorry for the bad English!

Comment: @CommonsWare I've added parts of the code for better understanding. Sorry for the bad English!

Comment: "as the target of my application is now is 11" -- that code is not going to work on Android 11+. You do not have write access to arbitrary locations on external storage, such as custom directories under the external storage root directory. You could switch to using `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context` instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, and you should have better luck.

Comment: Also try File.canRead() before you try to read your file. Of course an app should be able to read a file which it first created.

Comment: Thank's everyone for the solution:

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/FVN/";
        } else {
            return context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/FVN/";
        }